# Arabic charachters are not generated in PDF with latex

Tags: xetex, arabic

I'm using *pandoc* to generate PDF files and I've installed *MiKTeX* for latex libraries.

I have a *.tex* file contains Arabic and English charachters.
when I compile the file it generates a PDF file without arabic charachters.
here's the command I execute:

`pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex khaled.tex -o khaled.pdf`

and here's the *tex* file content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Junicode}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
    [Script=Arabic,        % to get correct arabic shaping
     Scale=1.2]            % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
    {Scheherazade}         % whatever Arabic font you like

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1] % Arabic inside LTR
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\n}         [1] % for digits inside Arabic text
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\afootnote} [1] % Arabic footnotes
           {\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}
\newenvironment{Arabic}     % Arabic paragraph
           {\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\arabicfont}{}

\begin{document}

English text ``\textarabic{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}'' with Arabic in
between. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned.

\begin{Arabic}
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين \n{١٢٣٤٥} فقرة عربية
محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين\afootnote{حاشية عربية.} فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are compiling with XeLaTeX but using `\luatextextdir` which is a LuaTeX command. I would recommend compiling with XeLaTeX and using `polyglossia` (which loads the `bidi` package) to deal with the language commands instead of using your own commands.

Comment: What error messages do you get? Did you look at them? Can you include the contents of the generated `.log` file? Also, can you remove any previously generated PDF and try again, to make sure that a PDF is even generated in the first place? Your file doesn't compile for me because `\luatextextdir` and `\luatexpardir` are undefined… but maybe they are for you? See what the errors say.

Comment: Offtopic: interesting fact about Unicode: `{١} ف` displays in my browser with two opening braces `{` and `{`, even though it contains one opening `{` and one closing `}`.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks for your instant replay, but pardon me I'm new to this stuff, I don't know how to use *polyglossia* while compiling?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks for your reply, from the log I've found that the font isn't on my machine and I've changed it to `Amiri` but I've encountered an error too.        

`khaled.tex 21 Undefined control sequence.
\textarabic #1->\bgroup \luatextextdir                                     TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup 
l.21 ...عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}
`
How could I configure \luatextextdir and \luatexpardir? I'm totally novice at this topic :(

Comment: @Mohamed-aaa-Omran For the moment I would recommend *not* using `pandoc` (which adds an extra layer of complication) and learn how to typeset regular LaTeX documents in Arabic. See the accepted answer to this question: [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12347) Do not use `lualatex` for Arabic, it's really not ready to use for RTL languages. Use `xelatex`.  So all of your `\luatextextdir` code etc. should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'de like to thank @Alan Munn and @ShreevatsaR and @khaled Hosny for putting me on the road.
I asked this question with zero knowledge in LaTeX and after 6 days in reading and trial&error, I've gathered enough information to lead the way :)

**Solution:**
first thing I did is using packages that are compatible with the *XeLaTeX* enging. I used `\usepackage{polyglossia}`

and finally passing the parameter `lang:ar` 
here is the full command line I've used:
`pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex -V mainfont:"Amiri" -V lang:ar -V dir:rtl -H include.tex khaled.md -o khaled.pdf`